# media query doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Seems like i've done everything correctly, but it just wouldn't not work. It doesn't display when inspecting element as well. 
To check if it's media query, tried setting a different bg color.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1050px) {
  #hmbn {
    width:400px !important;
    background-color:red !important;
  }
}
```

The div is placed inside bootstrap row

http://jsfiddle.net/CH8Hb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CH8Hb/3/) you go.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1050px) {
    #hmbn {
        width:400px;
        background-color:red;
    }
    .im1fill {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Explanation: `#hmbn` didn't receive I height, which was caused by `a` not displaying as block, which was caused by the floating of the divs inside the anchors. Remove the float, and you fix everything. You can get rid of the `!important` tags as well.

Comment: ok. it works. Tnx! But now, i'm presented with a problem, where i still need these divs inline at that width.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the floating elements within `#hmbn`

Bootstrap has a buiilt in clearfix. Add the class `clearfix` to `#hmbn`

```
<div id="hmbn" class="clearfix">
    ...
</div>
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CH8Hb/6/)

---

The following no longer applies after the question was edited...

Remove the `;`

`@media screen (max-width:1050px) {`

Comment: Then you need to set up a jsfiddle showing the issue because there is nothing wrong with that code - http://jsfiddle.net/K23xk/1/

Comment: do you think it could be because of bootstrap, or should i skip the "row"?

Comment: Even if bootstrap was overriding your query you would still see it listed when inspecting the element. Are you sure the CSS file is being loaded?

Comment: yes. everything else is working. added fiddle link to main post

Comment: It'd be better to remove the float. It isn't necessary at all.

Comment: @BramVanroy if you remove the float the elements wont be on the same line

Comment: See my answer: remove 'em only when it is necessary. In the media queries that is.

Comment: .. and look at the comment underneath your answer. That's not what the OP wants

Comment: He seems to have edited his comment. I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work fine!

```
@media (max-width: 1050px) {
    #hmbn {
        width:400px;
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UxM4S/)

**VERY IMPORTANT:**

this will work fine:**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UxM4S/2/)**

```
@media (max-width: 1050px) {/*1.position*/
    #hmbn {
        width:400px;
        background-color:red;        
    }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {/*2.position*/
    #hmbn {
        width:40px;
        background-color:orange;        
    }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {/*2.position*/
    #hmbn {
        width:10px;
        background-color:green;
    }
}
```

because the computer is reading it from the top to the bottom and overwrite the style

this will not work: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UxM4S/1/)**

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {/*1.position*/
    #hmbn {
        width:10px;
        background-color:green;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {/*2.position*/
    #hmbn {
        width:40px;
        background-color:orange;        
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1050px) {/*3.position*/
    #hmbn {
        width:400px;
        background-color:red;        
    }
}
```

Comment: I've put the code at the very top of the sheet, and there are no other media queries. Still didn't work.